# C# SaveAs Excel error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to save a pipe delimited text file into an excel worksheet format. I am having some errors in the code, below is my code:

```
TextFile.SaveAs(Filename:=strExcelOutputFilename,
                FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
```

Where `TextFile` is an Excel.Workbook object (Editor's note).

I am having some syntax errors at TextFile.SaveAs portion. Please help me identify any other errors if I have made them, thanks alot!

---

EDIT:
After correction of `:=` to `:` (Editor's note)

Below is a screenshot of the lines i am having error at, as well as the error list:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` is not a valid C# operator, you just need `:`

Example:

```
TextFile.SaveAs(Filename: strExcelOutputFilename, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178843.aspx

Comment: after i removed them, ":strExcelOutputFilename, FileFormat" are underlined in red and it seems to have a syntax error in them :/

Comment: There's more to debugging than just looking if there's a red line. Open your Error List (View > Error List), try to compile, and read what the error says.

Comment: Ah, good! But it doesn't speak much, does it? I don't know what it is at this point, I can't see it. Try removing your FileFormat for a minute, see what it gives you.

Comment: It still says ; expected, with strExcelOutputFilename underlined after removing FileFormat